# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED when trying to open Nav Canada Website

Tags: python, html, css, ssl, python-requests

I created a script which scrapes the latest aviation weather data from the Nav Canada website at the following address;

https://flightplanning.navcanada.ca/cgi-bin/lab/lab.cgi?Langue=anglais&NoSession=NS_Inconnu&TypeBrief=L&Version=T&AerodromeId=CYOW&cw_metar=dcd_metar&fw_gfaCld=on&fw_gfaIcg=on&rwt_uprWindsFD180=on

I use this data to calculate a few variables and display it on my own web server using a raspberry pi. I came across this error a few days ago after many months of no trouble. I tried switching the link to a different website to see if it was a bug with the request module but other websites work fine. Is it possible I got banned somehow from accessing their site this way? I can still access it through my browser. Or is their another underlying problem that I have not thought of? Here is the stack trace.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1400, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 401, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 808, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Philip Naida/Google Drive/Projects/WeatherDataCollector/WeatherDataCollector v_5.0/WeatherDataCollector.py", line 15, in <module>
    source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://flightplanning.navcanada.ca/cgi-bin/CreePage.pl?Langue=anglais&NoSession=NS_Inconnu&Page=forecast-observation&TypeDoc=html').read()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)>
```

If you can, could any of you try to access this webpage using urllib and see what happens? Any help would be appreciated I would like to get my server back online.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [report from SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=flightplanning.navcanada.ca) for this site you will see among many other warnings:

> This server's certificate chain is incomplete.

If you look into more details you'll see that the server is providing only the leaf certificate but is failing to provide an intermediate certificate which is needed to build the trust chain to the local root certificate.

Desktop browsers often (but not always) work around such misconfigured servers by trying to automatically get the missing certificate from somewhere else. But other applications (like Python, Perl, Java... applications) simply fail since the certificate can not be properly validated without having the missing intermediate certificate.

To work around this server you need to provide the intermediate certificate yourself. This can be done for example with requests like this:

```
import requests
response = request.get('https://flightplanning.navcanada.ca', verify='mycerts.pem')
```

With `mycerts.pem` containing all the missing intermediate certificates and the root certificate you trust. You can find such a file which fixes the connectivity with this specific server at https://pastebin.com/zi5BN2Vt

Comment: Thank you for the help guys! I will try to get the missing certificate myself first because I don’t want to skip over the verification. I’ll try it as soon as I can to see if it works.

Comment: So I tried doing this but it did not work, I just want to make sure im doing it right. I'm using urllib.request' so I did the following `source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://flightplanning.navcanada.ca', cafile='mycerts.pem', capath='C:\Users\User\Google Drive\Projects\WeatherDataCollector\WeatherDataCollector v_5.0').read()`. I am getting an error that `'unicodeescape' codec cant decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`. I tried using each certificate and I got the same error for both.

Comment: @PhilipNaida: I have no idea where this error comes from but this has nothing to do with certificate validation. I've tried the code line you've shown (with a different capath and the mycerts.pem I've provided) and it works without problems for me. Is this really this line which is failing?

Comment: Interesting, did I create the mycerts.pem file correctly by copying only one of the certificates between where is says BEGIN CERTIFICATE and END CERTIFICATE? Or am I supposed to copy the entire thing?

Comment: @PhilipNaida: If you take my full `mycerts.pem` you don't need an additional `capath` since I've included intermediate and root certificate. But I'm not sure that the error you report in the comment is even related to this certificate validation issue.

Comment: Ah, I removed the `cafile` parameter and it worked like a charm. Now may I ask you how you knew exactly what certificate I was missing? I have a lot to learn apparently, I dont even know what `.pem` is haha. Thanks

Comment: @PhilipNaida: the SSLabs report I've linked to shows the expected certificate chain including the missing intermediate certificate. Starting from this one can Google for the sha256 fingerprint shown by SSLLabs and after a while find these certificates. You could probably also look at the chain in the browser and export the chain and root certificates from there.

Answer (score -1):

The website is using TLS 1.0 (an obsolete protocol), RSA (an obsolete key exchange), and AES_128_CBC with HMAC-SHA1 (an obsolete cipher).  If you want to continue to use it, I would recommend using the popular `requests` package.  It allows you to turn off server verification when sending a request.

```
import requests

url = ('https://flightplanning.navcanada.ca/cgi-bin/lab/lab.cgi?Langue=anglais' 
       '&NoSession=NS_Inconnu&TypeBrief=L&Version=T&AerodromeId=CYOW&cw_metar='
       'dcd_metar&fw_gfaCld=on&fw_gfaIcg=on&rwt_uprWindsFD180=on')

res = request.get(url, verify=False)

# you will get the following warning
InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate 
verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io
/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings    InsecureRequestWarning)

res
# returns:
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: TLS protocol version, key exchange and cipher are unrelated to certificate validation.

Comment: I simply copied the error code reported by google chrome.

Comment: Do you mean the *information* shown in the security tab in the developer tools of Chrome starting with "Obsolete connection settings"? This is no *error code* but just information about the quality of the security of the connection. If there would be an error or even unacceptable weak security Chrome would not display the content of the site. But your proposal of simply skipping certificate validation undermines the security of the connection a lot, way more then these non-optimal security settings used by the site.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, yes, load the page in Chrome.  Ctrl+Shift+I to inspect.  Go to Security tab, the information provided in the security overview.